# MVC 4 List Model returning null to the controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, list, asp.net-mvc-4, null

Here's my code:

**Models**

```
public class InformationsModel
{
    public List<InformationModel> infos { get; set; }

    public InformationsModel()
    {
    }
}

public class InformationModel
{
    public InformationModel() {

    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public string Group { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public bool Avaiable { get; set; }    
}
```

**View**

```
@model InterfaceWeb.Models.InformationsModel


@using (Html.BeginForm("UpdateInformations", "Main", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "frmInformations" }))
{    
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.infos)                
}
```

**Template**

```
@model InterfaceWeb.Models.Information.InformationModel

<div class="infoMain">
    <div class="colunas">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Name, new { style = "width:250px;" })
    </div>
    <div class="colunas">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Value, new { style = "width:120px;" })
    </div>
    <div class="colunas">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Group, new { style = "width:120px;" })
    </div>
    <div class="colunas">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Type, new { style = "width:150px;" })
    </div>
    <div class="colunas">
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.Avaiable, new { style = "width:10px; margin-left:20px;" })
    </div>
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UpdateInformations(InformationsModel infos)
{                

}
```

And when I reach the controller, my model is empty and I can't figure out why.

I tried to change the template, the view, initialize the list after, before, but nothing worked..

Thx for any help! =)

Comment: Your view is displaying what you intended?

Answer (score 2):

You're experiencing this problem because of the way model prefixes work.  Specifically, the problem is here:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UpdateInformations(InformationsModel infos)
{             

}
```

If you take a look at the HTML that your template generates, you'll see that it's along the lines of this:

```
<input id="infos_0__Name" name="infos[0].Name" type="text" value="" />
```

In this case, the important thing to know is that `infos` is the prefix associated with the values of your `InformationsModel.infos` property.  By also naming the parameter in your controller `infos`, you're throwing off the model binder.  You simply need to rename it to pick up the values, like so:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UpdateInformations(InformationsModel model)
{             

}
```

As an aside, I'd recommend renaming `InformationModel` to something more suitable, like `Person`, `Employee` or whatever it is you're modelling.  It was a little difficult following what you were trying to do, just because the class names are almost identical and the names don't really convey their intent.

Comment: Thank you!

I have a multi-project solution where I'm referencing a Class Library. I had to create a model to allow file uploading and this was the solution to my problem. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is probably with naming of things :)

Change your controller:

```
[HttpPost] public ActionResult UpdateInformations(InformationsModel infos) { }
```

With:

```
[HttpPost] public ActionResult UpdateInformations(InformationsModel model) { }
```

OR in your model change list name "infos" into something else.

Example:

```
public class InformationsModel
{
    public List<InformationModel> infos { get; set; }

    public InformationsModel()
    {
    }
}
```

Change with:

```
public class InformationsModel
{
    public List<InformationModel> anothername { get; set; }

    public InformationsModel()
    {
    }
}
```